# Need Help Working with Law of Sines/Law of Cosines in Java

Tags: java, trigonometry

I'm doing a project where I have to find the angles of a triangle given the side lengths, and I figured writing a program would simplify things. However, my code isn't working.

```
int a, b, c; // distance lengths
double A, B, C; // angle measurements

public FootprintSet(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC) {
    a = sideA;
    b = sideB;
    c = sideC;  
    computeAngles();
}

private void computeAngles() {
   A = Math.acos((b * b + c * c - a * a)/(2.0 * b * c)); // law of cosines
   B = Math.asin((Math.sin(A) * b)/a); // law of sines
   C = 180 - (A + B); 
}

public int getPacing() {
    return (int)(A+0.5);
}

public int getStride() {
    return (int)((C + B)/2.0 + 0.5); // average of two stride angles
}
```

For whatever object I create, getStride() always returns a value that rounds to 89, and getPacing() always returns a value that rounds to 2 or 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You are using int instead of float/double.

Comment: You are assuming degrees instead of radians.

Comment: You should do all of your calculations with a `doubles` and truncate to an `int` only for the final result, if then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C = 180 - (A + B);
```

This tells me that you are using degrees.

However, `Math.sin` takes in radians.

Try using `Math.sin(Math.toRadians(A))` instead.